# Get time in milliseconds based on a given time zone (Local time zone)

Tags: java, date, time, timezone, unix-timestamp

It seems to be a wrong question but hear me out. When i call System.currentTimeMillis() it gives me seconds which when I convert to human readable format from an online milliseconds to date converter gives me GMT or UTC time but not my local time. Is there a way to get the current local time in millisec as I see there is a change of millsec value on online converter when I enter my local time in it.

To summarize, my problem is to get the current local time in milliseconds which some how is different from what I get using System.currentTimeMillis() function in java.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`TimeZone.getOffset(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getOffset-long-) which gives *the amount of time in milliseconds to add to UTC to get local time*. Something like,

```
long date = System.currentTimeMillis();
int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(date);
System.out.printf("%d + %d = %d%n", date, offset, date + offset);
```